# Magento 2 How to pass variable from Controller to Observer on checkout_cart_product_add_after event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, controllers

I'm trying to send a $price variable from a controller where I add to cart my product to checkout_cart_product_add_after event observer.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function execute(){
        $request = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $product_id = $request['product_id'];
        $params = array(
            'formKey' => $this->formKey,
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $productFactory = $this->product->create();
        try{
            $product = $productFactory->load($product_id);
            $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);
            $this->cart->save();
        }
        catch(\Exception $e){
            return $request;
        }
    }
```

Here is my Observer

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');         
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $price = 44; //I wan't to get this from Controller
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
```

So basically I just wan't to pass from Controller a param to Observer, the $price.

Creating a variable session seems too much trouble considering that hundreds of customers will use the ecommerce at the same time. Maybe a cookie?

Thanks and greetings!

**UPDATE**

I have tried this on controller:

```
             foreach($items as $item) {
                $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                    'checkout_cart_product_add_after',
                    ['quote_item' => $item, 'price' => 50]
                );
              }
```

And this on Observer

```
$price = $observer->getEvent()->getData('price');
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use session variable to set and retrive value/variable anywhere in magento.

```
class yourController {
        protected $session;
    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session,
            ...
        ){
            $this->session = $session;
            ...
        }
    
        public function execute(){
            $this->session->start();
            $this->session->setCustomPrice($price);
            /*below 2 line add in your observer*/
            $this->session->getCustomPrice();
            $this->session->unsCustomPrice();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I did this before you answered, but I will give you the poin :D

Comment: thanx for accept and happy to see you did it.